Equivalent definitions of somewhere injective curve
A J-holomorphic curve $u : \Sigma \to M$ (where $\Sigma$ is a closed riemann surface and $(M,J)$ an almost complex manifold) is said to be somewhere injective if there exists a point $z\in \Sigma$ such that $u^{-1}(u(z))=\{z\}$ and $du_z \neq 0$. It is a non-trivial fact proven in McDuff-Salomon introduction to J-holomorphic curves that if $u$ is somewhere injective, then the set of $z\in \Sigma$ satisfying the somewhere injective condition is actually dense in $\Sigma$ (section 2.5). Later in the book (section 3.2 p.49) an other definition of somewhere injectivity is given :

A continuous function $u : \Sigma \to M$ is called somewhere injective if there is a point $z \in \Sigma$ and a constant $\delta > 0$ such that, for every $\zeta \in \Sigma$, we have
$$
d_M(u(z), u(\zeta)) \geq \delta d_{\Sigma}(z, \zeta).
$$
This condition is independent of the choice of the metrics on $M$ and $\Sigma$ used to express it. Note also that, if $u$ is continuously differentiable, then this condition agrees with the notion of somewhere injectivity introduced in Section 2.5.

I am unable to prove the equivalence of the definitions and it is a bit weird to me, as the new definition clearly implies that $u$ must be an injective map (i.e. no room for even a finite number of multiple fibers).
And in fact, an homogenous parametrization of a nodal cubic curve $\mathbb{CP}^1\to\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ seems to have only one multiple fiber (at the node) and hence should be a somewhere injective curve with exactly one multiple fiber. Considere for instance $[s:t]\mapsto [st^2-s^3:t^3-ts^2:s^3]$ (the unique multiple fiber being $\{[1:1],[1:-1]\}$)
Related :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454222/is-a-simple-j-holomorphic-curve-injective-everywhere-except-for-finitely-many-po
Simple, somewhere injective and immersion holomorphic curves
Any help on proving or disproving equivalence of the definitions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

I think definition 2 should say that there is a neighborhood of $z$ where the inequality holds, not that the inequality holds on all of $\Sigma$. But I know nothing about this topic.

This is silly, I had misread the definition, it does not imply injectivity and it is not too hard to show that the two definition are indeed equivalent. If someone needs help for equivalence of definitions at some point give me a head up and I will write an answer.
